ClassCastException with Hilt when trying to inject ViewModel in FavoriteActivity
I’m encountering a ClassCastException error when trying to inject FavoriteViewModel with Hilt in FavoriteActivity. Here’s the full error message:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.chaidar.dicoding.submission1expertandroid/com.chaidar.dicoding.favorite.FavoriteActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.chaidar.dicoding.submission1expertandroid.DaggerMyApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC$ActivityCImpl cannot be cast to com.chaidar.dicoding.favorite.FavoriteActivity_GeneratedInjector

Here’s the relevant code:

FavoriteViewModel class with @HiltViewModel annotation:
@HiltViewModel
class FavoriteViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val getAllFavoritesUseCase: GetAllFavoritesUseCase,
    private val addToFavoritesUseCase: AddToFavoritesUseCase,
    private val removeFromFavoritesUseCase: RemoveFromFavoritesUseCase
) : ViewModel() {
    // ViewModel implementation
}


FavoriteActivity class with @AndroidEntryPoint:
@AndroidEntryPoint
class FavoriteActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val favoriteViewModel: FavoriteViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // Setup UI code and other initialization
    }
}


Application class with @HiltAndroidApp:
@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApplication : Application()



What I’ve tried:

Adding the @HiltViewModel annotation on FavoriteViewModel.

Adding @AndroidEntryPoint on FavoriteActivity.

Making sure @HiltAndroidApp is annotated in the Application class.

Ensuring that all modules using Hilt have the following dependencies in build.gradle:
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.x.x"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.x.x"


Running Clean Project, Sync Project with Gradle Files, and Rebuild Project.

Using Invalidate Caches / Restart in Android Studio.


However, the error persists. Does anyone know what might be causing this or any additional steps to resolve it? Thanks in advance for your help!

Create your View model instance in the way ,  below
private val favoriteViewModel: FavoriteViewModel by hiltViewModel()

